# Do I Need to Set the ASBD of a Core Audio File Player Audio Unit?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I've specified and instantiated two Audio Units: a multichannel mixer unit and a generator of subtype AudioFilePlayer.

I would have thought I needed to set the ASBD of the filePlayer's output to match the ASBD I set for the mixer input. However when I attempt to set the filePlayer's output I get a kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported (-10868) error.

Here's the stream format I set on the mixer input (successfully) and am also trying to set on the filePlayer (it's the monostream format copied from Apple's mixerhost sample project):

```
Sample Rate:              44100
Format ID:                 lpcm
Format Flags:                 C
Bytes per Packet:             2
Frames per Packet:            1
Bytes per Frame:              2
Channels per Frame:           1
Bits per Channel:            16
```

In the course of troubleshooting this I queried the filePlayer AU for the format it is 'natively' set to. This is what's returned:

```
Sample Rate:              44100
Format ID:                 lpcm
Format Flags:                29
Bytes per Packet:             4
Frames per Packet:            1
Bytes per Frame:              4
Channels per Frame:           2
Bits per Channel:            32
```

All the example code I've found sends the output of the filePlayer unit to an effect unit and set the filePlayer's output to match the ASBD set for the effect unit. Given I have no effect unit it seems like setting the filePlayer's output to the mixer input's ASBD would be the correct - and required - thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I didn't bother setting the filePlayer ASBD but rather retrieved the 'native' ASBD it was set to and updated only the sample rate and channel count.

Likewise I didn't set input on the mixer and let the mixer figure it's format out.

Answer (score 0):

How have you configured the AUGraph? I might need to see some code to help you out.

Setting the output scope of AUMultiChannelMixer ASBD once only (as in MixerHost) works. However if you have any kind of effect at all, you will need to think about where their ASBDs are defined and how you arrange your code so CoreAudio does not jump in and mess with your effects AudioUnits ASBDs. By messing with I mean overriding your ASBD to the default kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat, kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked, 2 channels, non-interleaved. This was a big pain for me at first.

I would set the effects AudioUnits to their default ASBD. Assuming you have connected the AUFilePlayer node, then you can pull it out later in the program like this

> ```
> result =  AUGraphNodeInfo (processingGraph,
>                            filePlayerNode,
>                            NULL,
>                            &filePlayerUnit);
> ```

And then proceed to set

> ```
> AudioUnitSetProperty(filePlayerUnit, 
>                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
>                      kAudioUnitScope_Output,
>                      0,    
>                      &monoStreamFormat, 
>                      sizeof(monoStreamFormat));
> ```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I've been meaning to answer this as I received assistance outside of SO. Basically I didn't bother setting the filePlayer ASBD but rather retrieved the 'native' ASBD it was set to and updated only the sample rate and channel count. Likewise I didn't set input on the mixer and let the mixer figure it's format out.